# Примеры Java Oracle Coherence

Tags: oracle, java

Помогите создать Hello, World с Oracle Coherence. И желательно немного объяснить, что там для чего, это будет многим полезно, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[The Coherence Examples](http://wiki.tangosol.com/display/EXAMPLES/Home).

> - Показывают, как использовать возможности Coherence во всех поддерживаемых языках.
> - Подобраны в виде коллекций кода, показывающих одну или несколько функций.
> - Обеспечивают единый общий способ для построения и исполнения всех примеров.
> - Содержат примеры исходных кодов.